# Testing the significance of differences in frequencies across treatments using $\chi^2$ test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, chi-squared-test, proportion, treatment-effect

I've run a small experiment and need to test the data by comparing the frequencies of different treatments, specifically, whether they are significantly different. I think the chi-squared test is appropriate, but I am not sure how to execute it because it's somewhat outside the range of my course.

Simplifying, the data looks something like this:

```
               A Choices (%)       B Choices (%)       Observations
Treatment 1:       40                   60                  n=30

Treatment 2:       65                   35                  n=30

Treatment 3:       70                   30                  n=30
```

How exactly would I conduct a chi-sq test?

Is it the best test for investigating differences in the frequencies of 'A' between treatment pairs?

Say, testing H0: Treatment1(% A Choices) = Treatment3 (% A Choices)

Is it also possible to do a test like 
H0: Treatment2(% A Choices) = Treatment3(% A Choices) > Treatment1(% A Choices)

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Verity and welcome to the site. Could you provide some more information about your study, for example are the same people in Group A (and Group B) undergoing all three treatments? Could you also explain what the "A Choices" and "B Choices" mean?

Comment: Different people undergo each treatment. The study is a multistage game of chance, culminating in participants choosing between Option A - receiving a certain amount of money, or Option B - taking a risky gamble with the chance to win a larger amount of money. The different treatments vary aspects of the game, and are expected to result in different distributions of A and B choices. I need to compare Treatments 1 and 2 to Treatment 3, separately, in order to see if they are significantly different. So A or B refers to their choices ie. the data outcome.

Answer (score 5):

@Michelle raises a good question--it depends on what the answer is.  However, at first blush, I suspect that you could just multiply your percentages by your N's and get counts for each cell.  Then you would have a straightforward 3x2 chi-squared test setup.  I get the following:

```
                A      B
Treatment 1     12     18  
Treatment 2     11?    19?  
Treatment 3     21      9
```

(Note that 65% (& 35%) times 30 does not yield a whole number, so I suspect there's a little more to it than exactly this.)  The basic chi-squared test of independence checks to see if knowing what row a unit belongs to helps you know what column it belongs to (and vice versa).  The [wikipaedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test) contains all the info you need on the test and how to conduct it.

It is possible to test just 1 vs. 3, and just 2 vs. 3; however, these tests wouldn't be independent.  I should think a simple chi-squared test is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have another look at that. Do you know any textbooks that are more detailed, as that would be really useful?

Comment: Any intro to stats textbook will cover how to run a basic chi-squared test. If you want a more specialized treatment, the first 2 chapters of Agresti's [Introduction to Categorical Data Analysis](http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Categorical-Analysis-Probability-Statistics/dp/0471226181) will do the trick.

Comment: Online you can find an extremely detailed description of conducting a chi-squared test at http://www.psychstat.missouristate.edu/introbook/sbk28m.htm.